# Не понимаю как в модели MVVM сохранять изменения в базу данных

Tags: база-данных, wpf, datagrid

Изучаю `WPF` в связке с базой данных, использую `entity framework`. Вывод данных освоил, а как - теоретически - должны сохраняться изменения проделанные в `DataGrid`? Может есть у кого пример? Все что я находил заканчивается на выводе данных или контекст базы вытаскивается на уровень формы (`SaveChange`). Но я так понимаю что это не правильно. Может просто накидаете, знающие люди, какие объекты должны быть реализованы?

Comment: Ну, по нажатию кнопки вызывается команда из VM, значения из VM отправляются в модель, и там вызывается SaveChanges.

Comment: Значит у меня какое-то свойство DataGrid не установлено, что оно не отправляет информацию об изменении контекста? ItemsSource="{Binding Path= table, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Comment: Ну, здесь проблем не вижу. А что означает «оно не отправляет информацию об изменении контекста»? Что вы имеете в виду под контекстом? И что есть у вас `table`?